# Selecting which overload is used in c++11

Tags: c++11

In the following code, as none of the arguments is const, i can't understand why the second overload is called in the 3 following cases.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void ToLower( std::string& ioValue )
{
    std::transform( ioValue.begin(), ioValue.end(), ioValue.begin(), ::tolower );
}

std::string ToLower( const std::string& ioValue )
{
    std::string aValue = ioValue;
    ToLower(aValue);
    return aValue;
}

int main()
{
    string test = "test";
    cout<<"Hello World" << endl;

    // case 1
    cout << ToLower("test") << endl;

    // case 2
    cout << ToLower(static_cast<string>(test)) << endl;

    // case 3
    cout << ToLower(string(test)) << endl;
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In all 3 cases you are creating a temporary `std::string`, this is an unnamed object, an R-value. R-values aren't allowed to bind to non-const l-value references (`T&`) and so only the overload taking `const std::string& ioValue` is valid.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that they "aren't allowed to bind to non-const references" applies only when talking about an l-value references. They happily bind to non-const r-value references

Answer (score -5):

The reasoning is the return type is std::string for the second function but void for the first. std::cout << (void) << std::endl is not a valid set of operations. std::cout << (std::string) << std::endl is. If you return a std::string& from the first function you'd probably see #2 & #3 probably use your first function call.

Comment: Overload resolution does not take the use of the return type into account. You'd just get an error if the `void`-returning overload were selected.